# update body with iframe

Tags: javascript, html, dom, node.js, iframe

I'm trying to change the body content (remove all the content) and then put there iframe:

```
function create_iframe(target){
    var link = document.createElement('iframe');
    link.setAttribute('id', 'target_u');
    link.src = target;
    document.body.innerHTML = link;
    max_iframe();
}
```

but it prints

```
[object HTMLIFrameElement]
```

what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`link` is a `<iframe>` element, not a string. Use the [`replaceChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.replaceChild) method instead:

```
document.documentElement.replaceChild(link, document.body);
//^^^^parent element^^^^  New element ^^^^, ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Old element
```

Or, a better approach, since `<body>` should be kept, use [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.appendChild), after clearing the body:

```
document.body.innerHTML = '';    // Clear contents
document.body.appendchild(link); // Append frame
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.body.appendChild(link);
```